# What implications has an irrational slope?

Tags: geometry

What does it mean that a line has irrational slope, i.e. what implications has this fact?

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is at most one point with rational coordinates on it.

Comment: Can you argue this, please? Thank you!

Comment: If $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are both points with rational coordinates, then the slope of the line joining them is $\frac{b-d}{a-c}\in\mathbb{Q}$